# Apostol: Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x+3x^3+3xy^2)^2+(y+3y^3+3yx^2)^2+x^2+y^2}}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

The following problem is from Chapter 8 of Apostol's *Calculus*, Vol II

> 4. (a) Find a vector $V(x,y,z)$ normal to the surface
>
> $$z(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}$$
>
> at a general point $(x,y,z)$ of the surface, $(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$.
>
> (b) Find the cosine of the angle $\theta$ between $V(x,y,z)$ and the
> z-axis and determine the limit of $\cos{\theta}$ as $(x,y,z)\to
> > (0,0,0)$.

I used the fundamental product of the vector equation

$$\vec{r}(x,y)=\langle x, y, z(x,y)\rangle$$

which is

$$\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial y}=\left \langle \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{3x^3+3xy^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, -\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{3x^3+3xy^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}, 1 \right\rangle$$

Then

$$\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial y}\cdot \hat{k}=\left\lVert \frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial y} \right\rVert \cos{\theta}$$

$$\cos{\theta}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x+3x^3+3xy^2)^2+(y+3y^3+3yx^2)^2+x^2+y^2}}$$

My question is how to find the limit of this expression as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$?

Answer (score 1):

We have that, by polar coordinates

$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x+3x^3+3xy^2)^2+(y+3y^3+3yx^2)^2+x^2+y^2}=$$

$$\small =\frac{r^2}{r^2(\cos\alpha +3r^2\cos^3\alpha+3r^2\cos \alpha\sin^2\alpha)^2+r^2(\sin\alpha+3r^2\sin^3\alpha+3r^2\sin\alpha \cos^2\alpha)^2+r^2}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{\cos^2 \alpha +\sin^2\alpha +r^4(f(\alpha))^2+1}=\frac{1}{2+r^4(f(\alpha))^2}\to \frac12$$

Comment: There are two terms summing up to $r^2$ in the denominator. Otherwise this is a sound approach.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes! indeed, I lost a $1$ in the last step! Thanks

Comment: This answer is different from jyrki's answer...which one is the right one?

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad I've determined the limit without the square root, so they are the same!

Comment: @user oh yeah, I see... thanks

Answer (score 0):

When $(x,y)$ is very close to $(0,0)$ the higher degree polynomials are tiny in comparison to $x$ and $y$. Therefore the denominator
$$
(x+3x^3+3xy^2)^2+(y+3y^3+3yx^2)^2+x^2+y^2\approx x^2+y^2+(x^2+y^2)=2(x^2+y^2)$$
making the answer $1/\sqrt2$.